# Continuous Rainbow color cycling effect in js

Tags: javascript

Just started learning JS and want to know how to create an effect in which VIBGYOR color keeps on cycling continuously using JS.
Here is my attempt https://jsfiddle.net/2t1kbm8u/.

```js
const scheme = document.querySelector("div");
const rainbow = [
  "#9400D3",
  "#4B0082",
  "#0000FF",
  "#00FF00",
  "#FFFF00",
  "#FF7F00",
  "#FF0000",
];

setInterval(() => {
  for(let colors = 0; colors < rainbow.length; colors++) {
    scheme.style.color = `${rainbow[colors]}`;
    scheme.style.borderColor = `${rainbow[colors]}`;
    console.log(rainbow[colors]);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Though all colors are being consoled but only the first and last colors are visible

Comment: It's because you run through the entire loop every single time your interval triggers. You should set a variable with `0` as value _outside_ of the interval. Use that variable to select the array index. Then increase it by one until you reach the last index. Reset back to zero and you're good to go.

Comment: i would suggest using css animations instead.

Comment: Instead of a `for` loop, use i++ to sequentially set the color on each interval and reset with `if (i >= rainbox.length) { i=0 }`

Comment: Here's a working example of what I meant above: [https://jsfiddle.net/b0uox52e/](https://jsfiddle.net/b0uox52e/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
   const scheme = document.querySelector("div");
  const rainbow = [
    "#9400D3",
    "#4B0082",
    "#0000FF",
    "#00FF00",
    "#FFFF00",
    "#FF7F00",
    "#FF0000",
  ];
  var currentColor = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    scheme.style.color = `${rainbow[currentColor]}`;
    scheme.style.borderColor = `${rainbow[currentColor]}`;
    currentColor++; 
    if (currentColor == rainbow.length-1) {
    currentColor = 0;
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: This will cause a small issue since `array.length` starts counting at 1 and index starts at 0. So `rainbow.length == 7` while the highest index is 6. You should also do `currentColor++;` at the end of the interval. Not at the beginning. Otherwise it'll always skip index 0

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot the index fix. Added it for you :)